# Ubuntu Server 18.04 won't boot after migrating to smaller hard drive

Tags: 18.04, server, partitioning, backup

I have a 1TB HDD with Ubuntu server 18.04 on it that I'm using as a games server: Terraria, Starbound, and UT2004.

I’m repurposing the drive and am going to eventually try to migrate it to a VM, but for now I’d like to put it on a smaller drive.

I shrank the partition using a GParted live disk and booted up fine. I pulled the drive and took another backup (of the now-shrunken drive) I switched out the drive with an 80GB drive and decided to use the Macrium Bootable Rescue disk to restore the backup (as a precursor to attempting to use the same ISO to restore the backup to a VM inside VSphere) I did note that the ISO is built on top of Windows PE, but I wouldn't think it should have any impact on restoring the image properly.

The restore finished but after rebooting to that drive it just sits there after POSTing.

Does anyone out there have any ideas? I suspect that GRUB is confused because of the hard drive size switch. I still have the original drive, so nothing is really lost or in any danger.

I can get any additional information anyone wants me to retrieve.

Additional information:

I used Macrium Reflect to image the disk

Here is the backup file info:

[image]

Existing host machine:

HP Compaq 6005 Pro Ultra-Slim

Configured for MBR

I'm running Ubuntu Server 18.04, so it should already have GRUB, I would think? Unless server uses something different than Desktop?

Full disclosure, I also posted this in Reddit in LinuxQuestions and Linux4Noobs, hoping for assistance, and someone asked for the COMPLETE process I used. In the event that I've left anything out above, here is that entry:

Complete process:

I pulled the drive and attached it to a machine I have dedicated for imaging, running Windows 7. I used Macrium Reflect to take a complete image of the disk.

I booted to a GParted Live disk and shrank the existing partition from 1TB down to about 40ish GB and rebooted.

I verified it booted up without issue. I then deleted the original backup and repeated the above process to take a backup of the now-shrunk partition with Macrium Reflect, which also completed successfully. I copied that backup to a portable USB hard drive

I used Macrium to create a bootable Rescue ISO (which is apparently built on top of Windows PE, if that matters) and used ImgBurn to burn it to disk.

I installed an 80GB SATA drive in the host machine and booted to the Rescue disk

I used a command prompt inside the now-booted rescue disk to run diskpart, select disk 0, clean to wipe the existing partitions off the disk.

I plugged the external hard drive into the machine and ensured it was detected

I then used the Macrium program to restore the image from the external hard drive to the 80GB drive.

It appeared to complete successfully. I rebooted the machine and it did POST, but it did not boot.

I realize all of the above is actually somewhat convoluted: I could have easily taken the backup, shrank the partition, verified functionality, took a second backup and then restored it directly to the 80GB all on the Windows 7 machine,but I was using this as something of a test run, in preparation for an attempt at migrating this machine from a physical machine to a Virtual Machine: take a backup, load the rescue ISO to VShpere, create a VM, restore the backup to the virtual disk and boot. However that is definitely predicated on whether or not I could move it to a smaller disk, since I'm for sure not allocating a terabyte of space on my ESXi host.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, why don't you install 18.04 from an installer CD/USB into a new drive?

Comment: Three of the downvotes here were the result of spam flags raised automatically by a system (SmokeDetector and metasmoke) which detected your question as probable spam. That is, obviously, in error. One of those flags has been retracted. The users whose accounts were used for the other two flags have been notified, and will likely retract those flags as soon as they see the notification. Alternately, a moderator will handle the flags and clear them. The detection was primarily based on a couple of keywords. Those have been downgraded as to their reliability in detecting spam.

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough reply re: downvotes

As for why not install 18.04 from a CD/USB, I'm not trying to "install" Ubuntu (though I'm quite familiar with doing so) I'm trying to migrate this instance of Ubuntu Server (I've got it JUST the way I want it :) ) to a smaller disk. Ultimately, I'd like to migrate it to my ESXi host as a VM, but for now, moving it off a 1TB drive to a small 80GB drive is my goal.
Thank you for your interest